# Sybase kill process from Interactive SQL

Tags: process, sybase, kill

I am trying to kill a Sybase process but no success.

**sp_who** returns, among others the line:

```
fid,spid,status,loginame,origname,hostname,blk_spid,dbname,tempdbname,cmd,block_xloid,threadpool
'  0','  14','running','sa','sa','server','       0','DBSOTEST','tempdb','INSERT','          0','syb_default_pool'
```

If I try to kill this process (**kill 14**) I have the error:

> Could not execute statement. 
>   You cannot use KILL to kill your own
>   process. Sybase error code=6104 Severity Level=16, State=1,
>   Transaction State=1 Line 1

**select syb_quit()** exists from my session but the process is not stopped.

**Observation:**
After a restart of Sybase server the process is there. It is this normal? I do not have any insert command that is running, or any other program that does the insert.

Any insert command in the any table of the DB does not work.
Any select command works.

How can I obtain the permission to insert in the tables of my database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be two questions combined: one about killing and one about permissions. Please raise separate questions for there.

As for the killing, your own process will *always* be there the moment you connect to the ASE server. And as the error message says, you cannot kill yourself.

When there are errors with inserting etc., at least post the error messages. Or talk to your DBA.